# AngularJS JSON array of objects length (Symfony3 FOSRest)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, parsing

I am struggling with a very very annoying problem on Symfony3 with FoSRest installed. So, i returns JSON like this:

```html
[
{
"id": 1,
"city": "Poznan",
"postal_code": "70-324",
"street": "Slaska",
"first_name": "Michal",
"last_name": "Duda",
"phone": "832894432",
"email": "op@op.pl",
"weight": 4
},
{
"id": 2,
"city": "Poznan",
"postal_code": "70-324",
"street": "Slaska",
"first_name": "Michal",
"last_name": "Duda",
"phone": "832894432",
"email": "op@op.pl",
"weight": 4
},
...
]
```

I recive it using Angular and trying to get length of this JSON object using:

```
function ($scope, Parcel) {
    var parcels = Parcel.query();
    var result = JSON.parse(parcels);
    var len = result.length;
    $scope.parcels = parcels;
}
```

and then i recive error (in chrome):

```
angular.js:12783 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at Object.parse (native)
```

I know that parser cant parse this JSON and thhats the problem. Iam 100% sure that format of this JSON is correct, i can iterate through it using ng-repeat and all is ok. I spent more than 3hours on finding solution and nothing ...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the entire JSON, or at least the end?

Comment: Are you sure its JSON, by that I mean an actual string and not a already parsed object? You are assigning to the scope the object before you send it through json.parse, if your bindings work it would look like its already parsed.

Comment: Your JSON sample is fine, could you post full json sample?

Comment: @Posio could you check content of variable parcels, after assign by Parcel.query() ? is it strings or already in json format.

Comment: There is full JSON: http://pastebin.com/nTZZJTVs
@mmtama - You've right typeof is "object"
But i still dont know how to extract number of objects insite this object :(
In chrome this object look like: http://s32.postimg.org/tkg1p23sl/Przechwytywanie.png

Comment: I have no idea how to count this objects.. Iam newbie in js and really need help.